# Scheduling a job in pentaho 5.0

Tags: pentaho, job-scheduling

I have a job which i want to work as scheduler.

I found that there is an option for scheduling a job in pentaho 5.0 from the start step input
which has scheduling options for interval/day etc..

But my question is will the scheduling happen even if i close the pentaho i.e spoon window?
Or should it be up always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look into how to create cron-job or screen in linux for the same, means you have to start your job in back-ground so it never die.

So in windows such facility is not available so in windows your tool should be up all the time for executing batch process.

Comment: @ Working hard hi, can you tell me briefly how to get my jobs running on linux?   I mean i have linux sever on cloud,so should i install pentaho on it?

Comment: yes you have to create pentaho environment , then you can execute your job using kitchen 
./kitchen.sh -file="/dev/pdi/pdi_transformations_jobs/job.kjb" (location of file) .

Comment: Okay,Also i will have to edit my job is it? like connections previously was windows-mysql now it should be linux-mysql? i have zero idea about linux..so pls dont mind

Comment: if you want to execute your job in cloud then you have to prepare environment for everything for pentaho, for database and then according to that you have to give cloud ip address in database connection.

Comment: Oh! lots to do then..Thanks @ Working Hard

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling takes place at the Data Integration server level. If you don't have a DI server running you need to schedule it using the OS scheduling facility (task manager on Windows or cron) and call the job or transformation by using kitchen or pan, resp.

Comment: nsousa can you post some links on how to use OS scheduling facility for task manager on windows or cron??

Comment: Please read the manual of your OS regarding scheduling services. That's not a pentaho question per se.